# How do I deal with traps in Pillars of Eternity?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

In the first dungeon, I've come across an area full of traps that will kill me if I step on them, and it's problematic in many different ways.

- My characters detect the traps, but if I click beyond the area, they'll happily walk directly over the trapped floor, which really should be considered a bug in the pathfinding code.  (If you can see the trap, obviously you're not going to step on it!)
- One of my party members is a rogue with the Mechanics skill, which should be usable to perform a Disarm Trap action.  When I point the cursor over a trap, it changes to a trap icon, but clicking just causes him to go step on the trap instead of trying to disarm it.  If there's a way to disarm the trap, it's not obvious in the UI.
- Trying to click precisely to walk through the trapped area without actually stepping on the traps doesn't work; they walk off to the side and get killed.
- Even when my character doesn't get killed by veering off a precise course, the rest of the party will happily follow behind and trigger the traps like bumbling idiots.  There really should be a "solo mode" command somewhere, but for the life of me I can't find how to activate it.

This is right there in the first dungeon, so I can only assume it's *supposed* to be simple, but I just can't figure out what it is I'm supposed to do to get through this trapped section.  What am I missing?

Comment: It's not a bug in the pathfinding code. Sometimes you just say "screw it" and walk over the trap and take the damage if you don't have any other options. If pathfinding prevented that, it would remove that option.

Comment: @Sterno: Oh, I can totally understand how you might want to do that in some situations.  And the appropriate way to deal with that would be to walk *onto* the trap.  But if my character is on one side of the trap and I click on *a safe spot on the other side of it*, I expect the AI to be smart enough to walk around the trap, not go blundering directly through it like a blind ogre.

Comment: I think they fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick to disabling some of the traps in that area, you probably already found it. This disables enough of the traps that you can cross the area, but not all of them:

> Light all the braziers in the adjacent room to disable some of the traps

You should be able to disarm the traps if you select only a single party member and click on them when the mechanics icons appears. I've no idea why this doesn't work in your case. Though I'm not sure if you can disable these specific traps at that point, my character wasn't able to actually disable them.

You can get your party across through the traps by moving each one individually. Just click on the portrait of one of your characters, you'll only move this one then. It's a bit annoying, but possible. There is also another way around the whole thing, so if you don't want to bother, just look for another way out of the cave.

Comment: I found the trick. That's how I know there's a way through.  But the broken pathfinding gets in the way of actually crossing it....

Comment: @MasonWheeler I just moved them manually around the traps, you can't rely on the pathfinding here. But the big issue seems to be that you don't control individual party members, that will probably fix most of your problems

Comment: With a few points in Mechanics, you can disable the traps that form the path that way, and get 15 XP for each disabled trap. (The traps that are not along he path that the fires would have carved out cannot be disarmed.)

Comment: Do you need to be in "scout mode" in order to disarm the traps?